# Select all records in which file does not exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which one column is full file paths. I would like to write a select query which will select each record where that path does not exist. I was trying to use xp_fileexist, but I'm not having much luck using it in a select query. What is the correct way to do this (doesn't necessarily have to use xp_fileexist)?

Comment: SQL Server is not really the right tool to do this with. But you can fetch the data in a cursor and call xp_fileexist in the cursor. Another option is writing a SQLCLR function.

Comment: @FilipDeVos - Alright, well, it won't be too much trouble to check them manually, there are only about 170, I was just hoping there was an easy way to do it.

Comment: something like this? (sorry for the pastebin. cant answer behind firewall apparently) http://pastebin.me/9c7119338e0214b998a648072211a69c 
[this is filip's idea with the cursor..]

Comment: @Karel-JanMisseghers - On the line `if xp_fileexist(@file_path)` it gives me the error `An expression of non-boolean type is specified in a context where a condition is expected.` And as a bonus, it also says  `xp_fileexist is not a recognized built-in function name`

Comment: I assumed xp_fileexist was a function you wrote/could call that returns true if the file specified exists. If this is the case it looks like theh function is not defined your current or master database?

Comment: @Karel-JanMisseghers - I keep seeing references to xp_fileexist, so I thought it was a system stored procedure.

Comment: I found this 'One option to validate that a file exists or not is to use the master.dbo.xp_fileexist extended stored procedure.  In a nutshell this extended stored procedure will validate that a file exists.  Unfortunately, master.dbo.xp_fileexist is not a documented extended stored procedure in SQL Server Books Online.  As such, be aware that the functionality may change over time, although to the best of my knowledge this extended stored procedure has maintained its functionality between SQL Server 2000 and 2005.' 
Here: http://tinyurl.com/file-exist-source

Comment: And I can't seem to find it in my master/extended stored procedures, where it's supposed to be according to this article.

Comment: Ah, perhaps the stored procedure has been removed in SQL Server 2008, then. I hadn't looked at the dates of the articles which mentioned xp_fileexist.